# Ejecucion de AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

Señores,

Me encuentro en una interrogante.
Estoy trabajando con `ASP.NET MVC` y estoy ejecutando `Ajax` via `post`.
El requerimiento es cargar dos grillas con un `Ajax` para cada grilla.
En estricto rigor seria algo así, Ejemplo:

**Controller:**

```
Public ActionResult grilla1()
{
return JSon(Datajson.cargagrilla1());
}

public ActionResult grilla2()
{ 
return JSon(Datajson.cargagrilla2());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Action("grilla1", "CargaGrillas"))",
        type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    //data: ({ "rut": firstName }),
    success: function (Result) {
        Grilla1(Result);
    }});
$.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Action("grilla2", "CargaGrillas"))",
        type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    //data: ({ "rut": firstName }),
    success: function (Result) {
        Grilla1(Result);
    }});
});
```

NOTA: Son ejemplos nada mas, no se necesita analizar el codigo solo su flujo de ejecucion :).

PD: La consulta es, como son dos ajax independientes, el recorrido de su ejecucion sera simultaneo o el segundo ajax va a tener que esperar que el primer ajax se ejecute y devuelva su data y cuando el primer ajax termine su ejecuccion se podra ejecutar el segundo Ajax??

Quedo atento a sus comentarios, espero se me hayan entendido.

Comment: Hasta donde yo entiendo tu pregunta, JS se lee y ejecuta linea a linea, por lo que hasta que el primer Ajax no haya finalizado, no se ejecutará el segundo.

Comment: @jonilgz No, son llamadas asíncronas, se ejecutarán las dos llamadas en paralelo

Comment: Tenia entendido que el ajax es asincronico, pero no tenia idea de que manera asincronica se estaban ejecutando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código realizará la primera petición AJAX, realizará la segunda petición AJAX y ahí acabará el hilo principal de ejecución.
Cuando el servidor responda a las llamadas, se llamará a las funciones declaradas en `success` en el orden en el que las respuestas lleguen: es posible que se ejecute primero la llamada de la "grilla2" o no, eso ya dependerá de la red y del servidor, nada garantiza el orden (por eso se llaman llamadas asíncronas).

Pequeña demostración con un comportamiento similar sin usar AJAX:

```js
function ajaxMock(url,callback) {
  console.log('simulando llamada a '+url);
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback('Esto es una respuesta');
  },Math.random()*100);
}

console.log('Hago llamada 1');
ajaxMock('http://ejemplo', function (respuesta) {
  console.log('La respuesta a la primera llamada es ' + respuesta);
});

console.log('Hago llamada 2');
ajaxMock('http://ejemplo2', function (respuesta) {
  console.log('La respuesta a la segunda llamada es ' + respuesta);
});
```

Si la ejecutas varias veces verás que el orden de la respuesta varía y, por tanto, el orden de la función llamada también.

Comment: lo que entiendo es que, independiente de su posicion se ejecutar los dos a la vez?...

Comment: Puedes asumir que son a la vez, sí. Se ejecutarán en orden pero el tiempo entre ellas será de milisegundos o incluso menos.

Comment: Ok, Entendido muchas gracias.!!